# An upper bound for the number of non-negative integer solutions of a linear Diophantine equation which k is not in the solutions.

Tags: combinatorics, linear-diophantine-equations

Let $n>3$ and $0<k<d-1$ be three natural numbers. Let the integer $a$ be the number of all non-negative integer solutions of the equation ‎$ x_1+x_2+\dots+x_n=d $‎ which $k$ is not in the solutions. Also, set $b=d^{n-1}-(d-k)^{n-1}+n-1$. Prove that $a<b$. The other words for the problem is
$$ d^{n-1}-(d-k)^{n-1}+n-1>c(n+d-1,d)-c(n+d-k-2,d-k).$$
Note that $c(m,r)=‎\dfrac{m!}{r!(m-r)!}‎$. It's well known that the number of all non-negative integer solutions of the equation ‎$ x_1+x_2+\dots+x_n=d $ is equal to $c(n+d-1,d)$.

It may be useful to remark that the left side (the integer $b$) is equal to the cardinal of the following set.
$$ ‎\lbrace ‎(a_1,\dots,a_{n-1})\in A ‎\mid‎‎ ‎‎\exists j‎: ‎a_j>d-k‎ \rbrace‎‎ \cup \lbrace 1,2,\dots,n-1 \rbrace  $$
which $A=‎\lbrace 1,2,\dots,d ‎\rbrace ^{n-1}$.

Comment: Do you mean that $x_i \ne k$ for all $i$?

Comment: Yes, I do. All solutions $x_1 ,..., x_n$ with $x_i \neq k$ for all $i$.

Comment: I've deleted my answer because I misunderstood the question. The inequality you state doesn't hold; try $(n,k,d)=(4,1,14)$. So you have to use a different strategy.

Comment: You are right. The integer $b$ can not be the upper bound. I have to look for another upper bound.